# Working atg Dynamo with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, repository, atg

I Was suddenly wondering of working **ATG** with **Object Oriented PHP**? Is it really possible? If not why?

**Example**

> :We use droplet to perform certain functions in ATG whereas same
>   functions can also be done in PHP.
>
> Also Why  Repositories(database)  will not work with PHP?

Answer (score 1):

The ATG framework is written in Java, to run within a Java VM.

The code that one writes, to customise, enhance or extend ATG, is deployed alongside existing Java code, to run in the same VM, and requires the developer to invoke methods on Java objects or to extend Java classes.

The framework provides tags for accessing ATG functionality from the UI layer. These tags are written in Java and implemented as JSP tag libraries, intended to run within a Java-based web application server (such as JBOSS or WebLogic)

PHP is an entirely different application framework. It does not run in a Java VM, and there is no simple mechanism to invoke Java methods from PHP code.

I would question what it is you really want to achieve? Is it that you need to make use of underlying ATG functionality, but prefer the syntax of PHP for UI code? Are JSP, JSTL and the DSP tags really that different and difficult to work with in comparison?

If you really want to continue to use PHP syntax but to make use of ATG features, you may look at some kind of PHP interpreter within Java - integrating an implementation of PHP to run in the Java VM. I believe that Caucho Resin is one such implementation, but I have no idea how stable, reliable, or featured it is. Even with that, you may not be able to use the DSP tags, and will need some other mechanism to bind to Java code from your PHP code.

Is it that you wish to re-implement the underlying ATG functionality into a PHP based framework? ATG has been actively developed, on a commercial scale, for around 20 years. Of course, you may not want to implement *everything* that ATG does, but take a good look at everything that the ATG framework does. You should have a clear idea of what it is you want to achieve.

If you do intend to re-implement ATG functionality as, say, an open-source commerce platform, you should also consider whether PHP is in fact a suitable language to do so (I suppose I am at risk of starting a flame war here).

In addition, you should bear in mind that when creating a platform (as opposed to a solution) you need to not only provide the basic business functionality, but also a mechanism for other developers to customise, enhance and extend. Especially in a way that does not hamper an upgrade path - so there needs to be a clear separation of what is in the platform and what is custom, but also with very easy access to modify or override that which is in the core platform.

Answer (score 0):

ATG is a **Framework** for how to build websites with specific modules for Personalisation, Shopping Cart etc. It is based on JAVA.

In the same way that the functionality exists in competing products to ATG, like WebSphere Commerce or Hybris, there is no reason why you can't build the same functionality in any language or platform of your choice. The question you should be asking is how much of that functionality do you want to build yourself and how much would you like to 'reuse' from the framework provided by the application vendor.